# How to toggle between browsers?

Tags: web-browser

I set chromium as my default browser by putting the following lines in my init:

```lisp
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "chromium")
```

Sometimes I need to browse with Firefox in private mode, which is feasible with the following setting:

```lisp
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "firefox"
      browse-url-generic-args (quote ("--private-window")))
```

I'd like to know how I could create a function (e.g. `defun open-url-incognito ()`) that could toggle (e.g. `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-*") open-url-incognito)`) between these two settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```lisp
(defun cycle-incognito ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((browsers '("chromium" "firefox")))
    (setq browse-url-generic-program
          (or (cadr (member browse-url-generic-program browsers))
              (car browsers))))
  (setq browse-url-generic-args (when (equal browse-url-generic-program "firefox")
                                  (list "--private-window")))
  (message (string-join (cons browse-url-generic-program browse-url-generic-args) " ")))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-*") #'cycle-incognito)
```

Of course for a simple toggle function you could replace the `or` form with an `if` (or a `pcase`), but the code above implements the more general version that cycles over a list (for a list of two elements this effectively becomes a toggle).

Comment: Great, thank you! It works like a charm. Just had to change `"chrome"` to `"chromium"`.

Comment: Great, I've corrected the answer. I also noticed that on some previous 'edit' of the answer, I removed the keybinding definition. I have placed it back, as I wanted to suggest using a global keybinding instead of the mode specific one.